# What's the use of these unknown metatags?

Tags: html, meta

I've been searching for a good article for the following meta tags and I didn't find much information in Google. Some of these are tags that I've never seen before. Imagine that even in Google it returned just 5-10 results with no words on how to use them.

PS: This question is not about telling me generic usage of the meta-tags. It's about specific metatags that don't even exist in the known metatag databases. For example "relatedTag".

Do you recognize them?

```
<meta name="contentTypeTag" content="Science Paper" />

<meta name="categoryTag" content="Engineering" />

<meta name="relatedTag" content="mechanical, engineering, elsevier" />

<meta name="allTags" content="Related:MIT,Related:research,Category:Engineering,Related:aerospace,Related:science" />

<meta name="pageTitle" content="Some title" />
<meta name="countryName" content="us" />
<meta name="languageName" content="en" />
<meta name="searchable" content="y" />
<meta name="pubDate" content="Tue Oct 17 12:00:00 EDT 2015" />
<meta name="pubDateDisplay" content="10/17/2015" />
<meta name="articleYear" content="2015" />
```

Comment: I would imagine they are custom meta tags for a particular CMS

Comment: That was my thought too. contenttype , relatedtag and alltags. I've never seen them before. I wish I could help you.

Comment: the only one that looks remotely familiar is `pageTitle` but even then I don't think that is right...if I were to *guess* they are custom attributes that are pre-defined.